# How to access JSON?

Tags: json, .net, asp.net-web-api, stored-procedures

I am wrote API method, after calling that method , I got my response like

```
[
    {
        "spark_version": "7.6.x-scala2.12"
    }
]
```

Now I want to have variable in my API method which store value 7.6.x-scala2.12.

**API Controller method**

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetTest(int ActivityId)
        {
            string StoredJson = "exec sp_GetJobJSONTest " +
                                "@ActivityId = " + ActivityId ;
            var result =  _context.Test.FromSqlRaw(StoredJson);
            return Ok(result);
        }
```

So how this variable should call on this response to get string stored in spark_version?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the JavaScript tag, here's how you'd do it in JS:

If you are able to call your API method, then you can just assign the response to a variable. For example, if you are calling it using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), it would look something like:

```
let apiResponse;

fetch('myApiUrl.com').then((response) => {
  if (response.status === 200) {
    apiResponse = response.body;
    console.log('Response:', apiResponse[0]['spark_version']);
  }
});
```

(I defined the variable outside the `then` to make it globally accessible)

Comment: So how this code will be written in API controller ?

Comment: Is your question asking how to write the API method? or how to access it?

Comment: my question is how to access response body into my API method which I have written above

Comment: And the answer above is how to do that in JavaScript, using the fetch API. I'm afraid I don't understand what you're now asking

Comment: okay got it. But i was writing code in .Net Web API

Comment: Ok, then you have the wrong tags. Can you remove the `javascript` tag and add the `.net` one instead?